# Влияние админ-панели на поисковую оптимизацию

Tags: seo, администрирование, поисковая-оптимизация

Как Вы знаете, по сути адимн-панель - отедельный сайт, который обращается к той же базе данных, что и сайт, которым мы управляем с админ-панели. Естественно, что в админ-панели нет никакой полезной информации и на неё доступ ограничен, потому если её поисковик проиндексирует, то скорее всего забанит. В этом нет ничего страшного, учитывая, что кроме нас туда никто не должен заходить, но ведь это может сказаться и на основной сайт, особенно если он находится на том же домене.

Вопрос: как избежать влияния админ-панели на поисковую репутацию основного сайта?

Comment: Я может что-то не понимаю, но как поисковик может проиндексировать админку?

Comment: Я, как любой другой пользователь интернета, ни раз видил на сайтах кнопку вроде вход для администраторов".  Если сайт админ-панели можно хранить на локальном компе, то зачем админ-панель встраивать в сам сайт?

Comment: Админка, разумеется, будет видна в интернете, однако для доступа к ней нужно авторизироваться с соответствующими данными.

Answer (score 4):

Если реализация админ-панели не содержит ошибок, то сборщик поисковика не попадёт в защищённые паролем разделы. Кроме того, [почитайте](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=ru) о robots.txt и теге noindex.

Comment: Говорят что гугл не очень-то и обращает внимание на то, что написано в robots.txt несмотря на то, что сам же и дает указания этот файл создавать.

Comment: Я изменил ссылку в своём ответе, так будет понятнее.

Comment: Понял! Спасибо Вам за ответ.